# Connection timeout with TNetHTTPClient and Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I try to set a 6 s connection time out for non responding sites, on  a TNetHTTPClient with :

```
NetHTTPClient1.ConnectionTimeout := 6000;
```

But it doesn't work, the timeout seems always the same default ( about 1 mn)  Am I missing something with the ConnectionTimeout or with my code  ?

Edit :
OK, my mistake, for this tests I used a (bad) proxy and it was the proxy which was not responding. So it seems that the ConnectionTimeout is not efficient in case of not responding proxy. I will post mode code example with the problem.

Edit 2 : So it seems to be more a 'resolve timeout' than a 'connection timeout', the code :
First a classic connection all is OK (even if the timeout is not very accurate).

```
  TempTime := Now; //TempTime : TDateTime;
    try
      NetHTTPClient1.ConnectionTimeout := 2000;  // NetHTTPClient1 : TNetHTTPClient;
      NetHTTPClient1.Get('http://www.google.com:81');
    except
      on E: Exception do
        showmessage(E.ClassName + ' : ' + E.Message + ', Time : ' + IntToStr(trunc((Now-TempTime)*86400)));
```

end;

Now a not OK timeout (with a bad proxy) :

```
  NetHTTPClient1.ProxySettings :=  TProxySettings.Create('157.230.8.180',8080);
    TempTime := Now;
    try
      NetHTTPClient1.ConnectionTimeout := 2000;
      NetHTTPClient1.Get('http://www.google.com:81');
    except
      on E: Exception do
        showmessage(E.ClassName + ' : ' + E.Message + ', Time : ' + IntToStr(trunc((Now-TempTime)*86400)));
    end;
```

Comment: Show your *complete* code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hello David I edited my post, I'll put the code with en example.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't provided the target platform for your sample code. According to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient.ConnectionTimeout) `ConnectionTimeout` property is not supported under `OS X` and `iOS`. Setting `ConnectionTimeout` under those platforms has no effect.

Other than that you might be getting response timeout which occurs after a successful connection to server, but the server fails to serve the request within specified interval.

Unfortunately it's not possible to differentiate between the two by `Exception` class, because all you get is general `ENetHttpClientException`. At least you can see the difference in the error message - `sending` vs `receiving` (see below).

Sample code to test (Windows platform):
Connection timeout

```
NetHTTPClient1.ConnectionTimeout := 1000;
NetHTTPClient1.Get('http://www.google.com:81');
{ raises ENetHttpClientException with message 'Error sending data: (12002) The operation timed out'. }
```

Response timeout

```
NetHTTPClient1.ResponseTimeout := 1000;
NetHTTPClient1.Get('https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000');
{ raises ENetHTTPClientException with message 'Error receiving data: (12002) The operation timed out'. }
```

There are 4 different kinds of [timeouts supported by WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsettimeouts):

- resolve timeout
- connect timeout
- send timeout
- receive timeout

Current Windows platform implementation of `TNetHttpClient` always sets the resolve timeout to 0, connect timeout to `ConnectionTimeout` and both send & receive timeout to `ResponseTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks  for your complete and documented answer. My target is Windows.