# Getting timeouts constantly when sending RESTRequests to server

Tags: rest, delphi

I am sending requests (post and get) with Delphi's TRESTClient and TRESTRequest to a webserver. Said server is being developed by someone else.
When sending requests to the API I am getting timeouts seemingly randomly and often.

The strange thing is that this only seems to be happening when making the requests with Delphi. When using a fresh, empty project and just placing the components the timeouts still occur. When using Postman no timeouts occur, even if I send the requests as fast as possible (I thought at first that maybe too many requests were sent too quickly, but I cannot replicate this behavior in Postman and I sometimes get timeouts even on the first request sent).

Since searching the internet didn't turn up anything about it I am at a loss.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this? If not, how could I move forward to find the cause of the problem?

Edit: The problem has returned and I was able to narrow it down a bit more:
When sending a post request, the request is getting processed by the webserver, but I get a timeout on the client side waiting for a response. The dev working on the server is looking into it on his end.
Strangely a similar thing happens with post requests expecting a response to a different server, which makes me think that the problem is on my end after all (especially considering Postman is working fine)

Comment: What kind of timeout is it? There are 4 different kinds of timeout. See also [Connection timeout with TNetHTTPClient and Delphi 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416108/connection-timeout-with-tnethttpclient-and-delphi-10-3/56417821#56417821).

Comment: For now the issue has disappeared (without me changing anything) so I cannot provide more information. I will when it appears again.
It's all very confusing.